# Reading of Ports giving Null even though ports exists

Tags: java, ports

I have developed the following program to check what available ports are in linux environment.

```
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class ListingOfPorts {

    static Enumeration ports;
    static CommPortIdentifier commport;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        System.out.println(ports.nextElement());
        String type;
        while (ports.hasMoreElements()) {

            commport = (CommPortIdentifier) ports.nextElement();
            switch (commport.getPortType()) {
                case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL:
                    type = "PARALLEL";
                    break;
                case CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL:
                    type = "SERIAL";
                    break;
                default:
                    type = "UNKNOWN";
                    break;
            }
            System.out.println(commport.getName() + " : " + type);
        }
    }
}
```

Ports are available in the system and still giving me null in the output:

## Stable Library

```
Native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2
Java lib Version   = RXTX-2.1-7
WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch
    Jar version = RXTX-2.1-7
    native lib Version = RXTX-2.2pre2
null
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?
or is there any library or system issue?
Help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: "WARNING:  RXTX Version mismatch" - Obviously your Java lib of RXTX and its native part have different version. You need to provide the correct native lib.

Comment: Do check the following link as well which has resolved a similar issue https://github.com/c-flynn/Nunchuckoo/issues/1